# Is 貴 (your) a productive morpheme?

Tags: word-choice, morphology

Is 貴 a productive morpheme in Mandarin, or is it only used in fixed expressions that one should just learn?

Like, can I say «貴杯» for «your cup», or is that not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such usage of "贵"(noble) with nouns is restrictive as @r13 suggested, and is often related to some formal/business scenario.
there's no such expression as "贵杯", if you mean to be respectful, simply use “您”, e.g. "您的杯子", this will work in most of the cases (at least not wrong). The usage of "贵" may be more elegant, but inappropriate usage sounds embarrassing and weird (which is "弄巧成拙")

Answer (score 1):

貴 is a morpheme when it means "expensive". However, it can be used with other morphemes/words to form words that express respect, such as "贵姓"、"贵国"、"贵宝地" or "貴人"

- 贵姓 - Respectably your name?
- 贵国 - Respectably where are you from?
- 贵宝地 - Respectably your place.
- 貴人 - a noble person, or lucky man (我的貴人 - my lucky man).

Sorry, no such word as "貴杯".